# Laravel5 - how to correctly write route for search query string?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, laravel-5

I'm working on an app, where I should be performing search on a table containing users. However, I cannot figure out how to correctly compose the route in order to attach the view with the controller and back. My code is the following:
The view:

```
<form action='{{url(' users')}}' method='GET'>
<input class='form-control' type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search for user...">
</form>
```

The route:

```
Route::get('users?keyword={$keyword}', 'UsersController@search');
```

The search() in UsersController:

```
public function search()
{
    $keyword = Request::get('keyword');

    $users = User::where("username", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("firstname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("lastname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("email", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("phone", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")->get();

    return view('search', compact('users'));

}
```

Can someone please tell what would be the correct syntax? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route should be as:

```
 Route::get('users', 'UsersController@search');
```

And in your controller, you can get the query parameter by using `get` function of the request object, which you are doing already.

You can get the parameter by any of function as:

```
request()->get('keyword');
request()->input('keyword');
request()->query('keyword');
```

**Update**

Add the following import at the top of your file:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Then in your controller function inject it as:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->input('keyword');
    // or
    $keyword = $request->query('keyword');

    // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Then it gives the following: Missing argument 1 for get(), called in /Users/eak/Sites/laravel-exercise/app/Http/Controllers/UsersController.php on line 120 and defined.

Comment: You are using this `Request::get('keyword')`, right?

Comment: Yes, $keyword = Request::get('keyword'); as posted above.

Comment: Can you try this `request()->query('keyword');`.

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::query()

Comment: The url changes to http://localhost/laravel-exercise/public/users?keyword=john and nothing further happens. :-/

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing further happens"? Is `$request->input('keyword')` working now? If not you can test it using `dd` as `dd($request->input('keyword'))`.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Now my problem become, that Route::get('users', 'UsersController@search'); always redirects me to the search results, instead of the users homepage, haha.

Comment: Great:D .Would you mind to accept this answer if it solved your original question?

Comment: Thank for your help. I should then create another Controller in this kinda case, if the used one's get method is already occupied?

Comment: Yes, that would work. If you want more appropriate solution then you can ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  Route::get('users', 'UsersController@search');
```

> controller

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    $keyword = $request->get('keyword');

    $users = User::where("username", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("firstname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("lastname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("email", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("phone", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")->get();

    return view('search', compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: I get an error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::get()

Comment: @sklrboy `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` add this after namespace.

Comment: Now my problem become, that Route::get('users', 'UsersController@search'); always redirects me to the search results, instead of the users homepage, haha. Should I maybe create another controller, or what's a professional solution in this case?